# Parse text from an href

Tags: python, parsing, web, beautifulsoup

I want to parse the text from an href. The code from the website looks like this:

```
<ul class="ListSearches">
<li>
<a href="/example.com">Textiwant</a>
</li>
```

I tried it with something like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r  = requests.get("http://www.example.com")

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for ul in soup.find_all('li'):
    print(ul)
```

I get this output

```
<li><button class="button grey" id="btnEurope">Europe</button></l <li><button class="button grey" id="btnAsia">Asia</button></li>
```

when I only wanted the text from the href

Comment: That I cant get the Text

Comment: But what actually happens? Do you get an error? Is nothing printed?

Comment: The output looks like this:<li><button class="button grey" id="btnEurope">Europe</button></l
<li><button class="button grey" id="btnAsia">Asia</button></li>

Comment: @Kenny94gulliUser: `ul.get_text()`.

Comment: It works nearly I get only the text now but not the text from the href.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r  = requests.get("http://www.example.com")

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for ul in soup.find_all('li'):
    try:
        print ul.find_all("a")[0]['href']
    except:
        print "sorry Kenny94 gulliUser. this time soup failed  "
```